# In AWS if I have my web server in zone us-east-1a and the database server in zone us-east-1b will that hurt performance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Web server: us-east-1a
DB Server us-east-1b

The ping between them is under 2ms so I'm guessing it's fine but I wanted to check.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine. The additional latency is negligible. I would recommend setting up your slave server in a different AZ from you master.

Answer (score 1):

From the EC2 site:

> Availability Zones are distinct locations that are engineered to be
>   insulated from failures    in other Availability Zones and provide
>   inexpensive, low latency network connectivity to other Availability
>   Zones in the same Region.

Since they are both in us-east region Amazon's probably trying to make their "low-latency" promise real.

But what TomTOm said is totally true, depends on what you're doing. If this type of 2ms latency is your bottleneck you'll probably care.

Answer (score -1):

Depends what you do. Seriously. Also the traffic I think may cost. I work mostly on databases where "10g connection, same room" is a requirement for good performance. It really depends what you do.

Comment: My understanding is that inter-AZ traffic is free for AWS. Inter-region costs.

Comment: Free? Like what? No money - great. But the OP says 2ms latency and you may find out that this COSTS you. PERFORMANCE is also called cost in IT. 2ms is a lot more than in one room. So, if you do tons of round trips this has a HUGH cost in terms of adding latency like hell. You can gladly say this isn not cost when your site goes to a crawl due to many sql statements and adding needless latency.